# How to fill the Prometheus with test data?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I run local Prometheus in Docker. How I can fill it with test data?

For instance, I need to push the data of `my_metric{my_label="label_value"}` with pairs of timestamp and data like the following:

- 1518008444.819, "1"
- 1518008454.819, "2"
- 1518008464.819, "3"

Having test data (according to desired profile) allows me will play with various queries.

First and only idea that I have was to push data into PushGateway. I tried examples like [here](https://prometheus.github.io/client_python/exporting/pushgateway/) but there is no way to change timestamp (without digging in "private" variables starting with `_`).

Is there a way to generate test data? If it can be done in code then Python is preferrable. Also, I understand that I can write script that generates metrics data, but 1) it is too long to wait to provide long data series and 2) I can't precisely specify timestamp (it depends from scrapping policy, system workload, etc.)

Comment: When exposing data, you [can specify timestamp](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#comments-help-text-and-type-information) in format `metric{ ..labels.. } value timestamp`. I believe it's somewhat limited in how much into the past you can go, but for testing purposes might suffice.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are looking for longer ranges of data, consider [backfilling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#backfilling-from-openmetrics-format)

Comment: And finally, if all you want is to test your alert rules, you can use `promtool` for [rules unit testing](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/)